# How to control mouse scroll default value javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys How to control mouse middle button.. I want to override mouse wheel for example when I clicked wheel button..The browser is scrolling default value(I guess 112 ) but I want 200

How can I do that Sorry about my english

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach a event handler to `scroll` event of the window and set the `scrollTop` value. But I don't understand why would you like to do this.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $(this).scrollTop(200);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dM8JP/1/)**

Comment: http://www.21-19.com/  check out this site..  There is Recent link on the page's left... and There are events page's right.. The event's top of the page Top  equals recent link Top I want this and When I mouse wheel click second event top equals recent link top.. but Default value stopping this..I want.. mouse wheel click..every event top equals recent link top  I hope you understand me

Comment: and this codes you gave me.. it is doing 200 everytime scrollTop value I want.. 200-400-600-800 mouse wheel click every time and back 800-600-400.. bla bla The original is 112-228-..